# Change desktop icon size in Powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Writing a PS script to quickly set up devices @ work. I need a way to set this in cmd/PS, but extensive searching results in... nothing. Where is this preference even stored? I found:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size=32
```

But no matter what, this is 32 and changing it doesn't seem to change the size. Thoughts, SU?

Comment: You need to logoff and on again for the change to take effect as per [How can I modify the size of icons on the desktop?](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-modify-size-icons-desktop)

Comment: @DavidPostill I've noticed that when right clicking the desktop>View>Large, this value doesn't change in the HKCU key. Are you sure this is still where the value is stored?

Comment: It may have changed in Windows 8.1/10

Comment: RegShot found no changes in the registry after changing this setting on Windows 10, but it seemed a bit unstable so might not be compatible or something.

Comment: I, too, tried RegShot and found no changes. Not just to that key - anywhere important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my Windows 10 machine, this value is stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop` in `IconSize`. After changing its value, you must restart `explorer.exe`. Logging off is not required.

So you could use,

```
Set-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop -name IconSize -value 48
Stop-Process -name explorer  # explorer.exe restarts automatically after stopping
```

This also allows you to custom size the icons beyond the preset Small/Medium/Large.

[image]

Comment: I tried this on Windows 10 [Version 10.0.17763.475], and it didn't work. After toggling in the UI, and refreshing the registry, they key didn't update, either. However -- I found that if I right-click in the desktop, and choose "Refresh", then the registry updates.  So, for values -- 32 == Small, 48 == Medium, 96 == Large.